# Please say what my ecg means

Tags: electrocardiogram

[image]

Please say is there any serious issue .really worried.My report says 95bpm and otherwise normal ecg.

Comment: For future reference, questions asking for personal medical advice or a diagnosis such as this are off topic here and likely to be closed.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Your doctor should be able to interpret your results, we can't do it over the internet.

Answer (score 1):

This question violates rules; the only reason I'm answering is because it is normal.

It's got a regular rhythm with a normal rate, an axis around 30º, which is normal.
All segment durations are within normal limits, and I don't see any conduction blocks. The "Possible infarction" comment is an automated interpretation by the machine (more often than not, not very reliable) and is probably due to the extremely low voltage in aVL and V1 (which I think is probably due to a badly-placed electrode).

Nonetheless, the person who can (and should) give you the most qualified interpretation of this exam is the doctor who ordered it in the first place and has knowledge of your history and any other symptoms you may or may not have.

Comment: The ÂQRS is around +60º  (it is isodiphasic in aVL)

Comment: I used dIII to calculate because am assuming aVL is an artifact (way too little voltage)